# Getting certain string blocks from a STRING

Tags: c#, string

Here is a text: string **txt** holds this value.

> CREATE TABLE table_name1 ( column_name11231 data_type, column_name232
>   data_type, column_name3 data_type, .... )
>
> CREATE TABLE table_name2 ( column_name1 data_type, column_name2
>   data_type, column_name3 data_type, .... )
>
> CREATE TABLE table_name3 ( column_name1231 data_type, column_name2
>   data_type, column_name3 data_type, .... )
>
> CREATE TABLE table_name4 ( column_name1231 data_type, column_name1232
>   data_type, column_name1233 data_type, .... )

this is a sample. i will read it from a text file. then i just want to take each CREATE TABLE command in a string array. how could i take it? I have tried split and substring. but that was foolish. I have done it with a silly and uneffective way.

here is it:

```
string[] totalSp = Regex.Split(txt, "CREATE TABLE");
string[] output = new string[totalSp.Length-1];

for (int i = 1; i < totalSp.Length; i++ )
{
output[i - 1] = "CREATE TABLE " + totalSp[i].Replace("\r\n", "");
}
```

this give me the desired output. but i now this is poor coding. cannot I do it any simplier way?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Yes, the OP used Regex, just not very effectively. Please look at the last code snippet.

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem. For example, what if you had the string `CREATE TABLE [CREATE TABLE] (id int, [CREATE TABLE] varchar(256))`?

Comment: I'm not talking about `Regex.Split`, because it's really pure approach. I'm talking about standard Regular Expression Matching.

Comment: @PaulSasik: But if its the effectve way using regex also than will not differ much , i think he is just worrying but honestly i don't see problem with the approach

Comment: `txt.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: @Saurabh: Please see Ic.'s comment above and Tim S.'s solution below. The answer is a combination of those two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to find the statements, as long as you're not going to have much variation in the input.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(txt, @"^CREATE TABLE .+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string[] myArray = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.ReadLines` to get the lines, and it's easy enough to filter the empty lines out without regexes.

```
var commands = File.ReadLines("filename.txt")
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    .ToArray();
```

If there are other commands in the file besides `create table` then you can add a simple filter for that too.  Just add the below command after the other filter:

```
.Where(line => line.StartsWith("CREATE TABLE"))
```

Comment: The best, unless one statement can be split into couple lines.

Comment: Good idea. This is of course assuming there are no newlines in each query though.

Comment: @lc. Edit added in the event there are such lines.

Comment: In fact if I look at the markup for the question, there are actually hard line breaks (for example between the `,` and `column_name3` in the first query)

Comment: @lc. It's hard to say if that's the true input or an error putting it into the SO question.  I'll leave this until the OP says it won't work for him.